# scala: Ordering.by vs Ordering.on

Tags: scala, standard-library

What is the difference between `Ordering.by()` and `Ordering.on()` in Scala?

(Well, one is defined in the trait and the other in the companion object, and the implementation code is also different, but there must be a reason why the language needs both.)

Comment: Well, as you said, because one is in the object thus is a factory, and the other in the trait, thus being a combinator. They are both there to help you create newer `Ordering` instances out of existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [`Ordering.by`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering$.html#by%5BT,S%5D(f:T=%3ES)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering%5BS%5D):scala.math.Ordering%5BT%5D):

> This function is an analogue to `Ordering.on` where the `Ordering[S]` parameter is passed implicitly.

Basically the two are the same, it's just a matter of convenience depending of what is your context and what you're working with.

Comment: Can you please provide examples? In what case what is more convenient?

Comment: @18446744073709551615 if you want to create a new ordering out of nowhere, then something like `Ordering.by((foo: Foo) => ...)` is very convenient, more than doping `Ordering[Bar].on(foo => ...)` - However, in some other contexts it may be more convenient to call `on` on an existing instance.